# Magento Shopping Cart Rule not getting simple product attribute values

Tags: magento, rule, configurable-product, discount

On a client's store we have configurable products based on a custom weight attribute (4kg, 10kg, 12.5kg etc...). I've set up a discount rule so that the discount only applies to products that are above 4Kg.

However, i realised the discount is also applied to 4Kg products. It seems that it's not pulling the attribute from the relevant simple product but from the configurable product. When trying with SKUs it was pulling the SKU of the configurable product rather than the simple product.

Has anyone been able to get around that? I'm using Magento 1.5.1

thanks